# If the compiler is asking for more number of inputs as given in program then is there any mistake in program

Tags: c

I need to accept the number of employee and accept their name,employee id,basic pay,%da and hra and display the employee id and total pay

for the same I created a structure and then an array of structure to store information of n employee

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct employee{
    char name[20];
    int id;
    int bp;
    int da;
    int hra;
    int tp;
};
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int ar[n];
    struct employee e[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",&e[i].name);
        scanf("%d\n",&e[i].id);
        scanf("%d\n",&e[i].bp);
        scanf("%d\n",&e[i].da);
        scanf("%d\n",&e[i].hra);
        
        
    }
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
       e[j].tp=0;
       e[j].tp=e[j].bp+(e[j].da/100)*e[j].bp+e[j].hra;
    }
    for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
    {
        printf("%d\n%d",e[k].id,e[k].tp);
       
    }
}
output:
1
xyz
1004
2000
100
500
0 (This is the extra input that compiler is asking for)
1004
4500
```

Comment: Remove `\n` from all your `scanf` calls.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments, you need to remove `\n` from your scanf statements. Although this format makes scanf read the number and store it into specified variable, but "reading" continues and it lasts till non-whitespace character followed by \n is found

So your scanf statement which is looking like this:

```c
scanf("%d\n",&e[i].bp);
```

Should look like this:

```c
scanf("%d",&e[i].id);
```

I tested your code with above suggestion and it seemed to work for me:

```
c-posts : $ ./a.out 
1
xyz
1004
2000
100
500

1004
4500
```